# Adding Fractions Alternative Ways

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to add two fractions class objects.
Below I used the gcd(greatest common factor) function to create a method for the fractions class.

Are there any alternative ways we can find sum of two fractions without using gcd?
And any reference to how gcd is implemented?

```
import fractions


class Fraction(object):
    def __init__(self, num, denom):
        self.num = num
        self.denom = denom
    def __str__(self):
        return f'({self.num}/{self.denom})'
    def gcd(self): 
        gcd = fractions.gcd(self.num, self.denom)
        return gcd
    def __add__(self, other):
          gcd_self = self.gcd()
          gcd_other = other.gcd()
          top = (self.num//gcd_self) + (other.num//gcd_other) 
          bott = (self.denom//gcd_self) + (other.denom//gcd_other)
          return Fraction(top, bott)
a = Fraction(1, 2)
b = a + a
print(b)
```

Comment: Note this is built in: https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html

Comment: @jonrsharpe Trying to understand the implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `gcd` isn't strictly necessary. You can work with fractions without ever reducing them to their simplest form.

```
def __add__(self, other):
    return Fraction(self.num*other.denom + other.num*self.denom, self.denom*other.denom)

def __mul__(self, other):
    return Fraction(self.num*other.num, self.denom*other.denom)

def __eq__(self, other):
    return self.num*other.denom == self.denom*other.num

def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.num}/{self.denom}'

# etc
```

This way, you really only need to simplify fractions in one place: `__init__`:

```
def __init__(self, num, denom):
    # Computing f is optional, to avoid storing unnecessarily large
    # integers and to simplify displays.
    # The class will continue to work if you simply set f = 1.
    f = fractions.gcd(num, denom)
    self.num = num // f
    self.denom = denom // f
```